# on delete link popup are you sure

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I have link  `<a href="/MyData/Delete/">` Delete data 
How can I implement onclick to popup confirm action with text `are you sure` and if yes selected to proceed to HttpPost action on MyData/Delete?

Comment: A link is a GET method! You going to have to use ajax to post your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<a href="/MyData/Delete/" onclick="someFunction(this, event)">
```

In javascript:

```
function someFunction(target, event) {
   if(confirm("Are you sure to delete?")) {
        var xhr;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
           xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else {
           xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
                 // successfully deleted
          }
        };
        xhr.open("POST", target.url, true);
        xhr.send();
   } else {
       event.preventDefault();
   }

}
```

More cleaner way of doing:

```
<a href="/MyData/Delete/" class="confirmlink">

document.querySelector(".confirmlink").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
       if(confirm("Are you sure to delete?")) {
           window.location.href = this.href;
       } else {
           event.preventDefault();
       }
});
```

Avoid using inline js scripts in HTML. It will pollute the markup and tough to manage later.

Comment: There is only one problem here I guess, when the user clicks on an element within the link (say an image) the event.target will point to the image. I'm not sure however with inline events.

Comment: ok, is it possible using this script to send on post delete action or I  have to use jquery with post?

Comment: How would this _proceed to HttpPost action_?

Comment: @user1765862 Need to add ajax to fire the post request. Will update the code in few minutes. Currently traveling

Comment: @user1765862 updated answer with the post request for deleting